# dynamic array names javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, eval

I have a few arrays with like names.

```
ArrayTop[]  
ArrayLeft[]   
ArrayRight[]  
ArrayWidth[]
```

I am trying to set the name dynamically in a function and then set value.

I have tried many ways of dynamically picking the right array but have not come up with a solution.

```
function setarray(a,b,c){
    eval(Array+a+[b])=c
}

setarray('Top',5,100)
```

In this example i am trying to set.

```
ArrayTop[5]=100
```

Comment: why don't u use an array of arrays? so you know is arr[0] bot is arr[1] and so on

Comment: Or you could also use an object of arrays which would then allow you to have names for the arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing this in the browser, one possible solution would be to do:

```
function setArray(a, b, c){
    window['Array' + a][b] = c;
}

setArray('Top', 5, 100);
```

I would recommend that all your array's be contained in some object and not pollute the global namespace. So it would be more like:

```
var arrays = {
    ArrayTop: [],
    ArrayNorth: []
};

function setArray(a, b, c){
    arrays['Array' + a][b] = c;
}

setArray('Top', 5, 100);
```

I would not recommend using eval. Eval is not meant for this kind of dynamic evaluation and it is a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

Hash map will be a perfect tool:

```
var arrays = {
  top: [],
  left: [],
  right: [],
  bottom: []
};

function addToArray(name, index, value) {
  arrays[name][index] = value;
}

addToArray('top', 5, 100);
```

I took the liberty to give more explicit names.

I suggest also two good practices:

- do not use eval. Eval is not meant for this kind of dynamic evaluation. In your case, it's a performance killer
- do not polute the global namespace. In browser environnement, avoid adding stuff to window (which is global).

Answer (score 1):

Put all your arrays into an object:

```
var myArrays = { 
    top : arrayTop,
    left: arrayLeft,
    right: arrayRight,
    bottom: arrayBottom
}
```

And the to get an array you can just:

```
myArrays["top"][5] = 100;
```

Or you can skip defining the arrays as global variables and just do something like:

```
var myArrays = { 
    top : [],
    left: [],
    right: [],
    bottom: []
}
```

Which initializes 4 empty arrays which you can populate:

```
myArrays["top"][0] = 100;
```

or

```
myArrays.top[0] = 100;
```

However, if `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` all are related (refering to the same object), it might make more sense to create an object with those properties and create a single array of those objects:

```
function MyObj(top, left, right, bottom) {
   this.top = top;
   this.left = left;
   this.right = right;
   this.bottom = bottom;
}

var myArray = [];

myArray.push(new MyObj(1,2,3,4));
console.log(myArray[0]);

myArray[0].left = 7;
console.log(myArray[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNuF8/

Answer (score 1):

Why not indexing your array with an object?

```
var arrayNames=["top","left","right","bottom"]
var data=[1,2,3,4,5];
var arrays={};

arrayNames.forEach(function(x){
    arrays[x]=data;
});
```

So you could get your Array via Name.
If you randomize or autogenerate the names, no prob.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
function setarray(a,b,c){
    window['Array' + a][b] = c;
}

setarray('Top',5,100)
```

*However, you shouldn't be doing this. Use a 2D array or an object or something. The purpose of this answer is just to show that it CAN be done, not that it SHOULD be done.*

Comment: Using a multidimensional array assumes that `ArrayTop[0]` and `ArrayLeft[0]` are related which might not be the case. They probably are, but there isn't enough context in the question. If they are, I'd say use a single array of objects with a `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties.

Comment: The arrays are based upon the style of div objects.

Comment: oops yes they are all related

Answer (score 0):

You missed, that Array has to be a String => "Array".
Then you can do

```
var postfix = "Top"; 
var a = eval("new Array"+postfix);
a.push(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var someArr = {

};
someArr.ArrayTop = [];

function setarray(a, b, c) {

    var arrName = "Array" + a;
    someArr[arrName][b] = c;
}


setarray('Top', 5, 100)

alert(someArr.ArrayTop[5]);
```

Hope this works.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linux_nerd/w5Q9P/)