# Calling array names dynamically inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm pretty sure this question is going to get negative response as many people have already asked it in SO. But trust me I have read every single answer of every single question none helped.

I know that in jquery you can put the array key name dynamically like this: `somearray1["abc" + variable]` but I'm not looking for that. I want to call the array name dynamically like:

```
var i=1;
console.log( "somearray" + i["abc" + variable] )
```

Can someone tell me how is it possible? I cannot put it in another array and call that as I'm building a very dynamic script, so I must need to call the array name dynamically.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use eval() as your last resort.

Comment: but using eval is bad as per as I know due to security reason.

Comment: You tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566160/dynamic-array-names-javascript

Comment: how would you do `i[....]` if i is a number, not an array or object? Perhaps you need to clarify the question...

Comment: @RickS yes I saw that but it didn't help. As I said I cannot put it inside another array or things like that. I need to directly call it dynamically.

Comment: As we don't really have more context about where that code is, have you tried to use `this['i']` to access `i` in your scope ?

Comment: Using eval is not problematic security-wise in your case. It's just a horrible design practice. Why not use a 2d array? somearray[i]["abc"+variable]

Comment: @yezzz I dont understand your question brother. i hold number like 1, 2, 3 and so on and the array name is someArray1, someArry2, SomeArray3 and so on....

Comment: ah I see "somearray" is array name, not text string ;)

Comment: @BlažZupančič trust me brother if I could do that I would not have asked for this in the first place. It's a part of a wordpress shortcode plugin which passes its data to js with new array name each time.

Comment: @yezzz exactly. The full array name is somearray then a number like 1, 2, 3 and so on. but I need to add that number dynamically making the full array name.

Comment: Try this  console.log(eval("somearray"+i+'["abc'+variable+'"]'))

Comment: @MohammedRaja eval is the shortcut way and it always works but everyone will suggest not to use eval as much as possible as it has many flaws and sometime can cause security issues too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly, your array depend from this.

```
this["somearray" + i]["abc" + variable]
```

```js
var bob1 = [1,2,3];
var name = "bob";
console.log(this[name+"1"][0])
```

Comment: I will try this out and let you know. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `window["somearray" + i]["abc" + variable]`?

Comment: Depend of your scope. Windows is part of the main scope. This refer to the local scope and the first thinks that jquery do is to create is own scope.

Comment: @GeraldChablowski thanks a lot brother. Yah I see it. Actually it is 2am here and I must need to get some sleep as I haven't slept for 2 days now. So I really have no strength to change all of my code to test it. But thanks a lot for your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here from your example. Do you want to console.log the value held at a dynamically changing position of "somearray"? If so, array positions are numerical indices (e.g. `somearray[1]`) and cannot be accessed via strings.

Are you trying to access an object property (e.g. `someObject1["abc" + variable]`) alternatively?

If it's an object property you are trying to access with changing parameters, you might want to try using ES2015 template literal syntax.

```
let i = 1;
let someObjectName = `someObject${i}`;
console.log( someObjectName[`abc${variable}`] );
```

That way the concatenation of the object name and its property will happen dynamically. I hope this helps.